# How to convert the ancestor class to the parent class and after back correctly?

Tags: c++, oop

I convert an object of class B to class A, after which I try to convert class A back to B, but an error occurs. How to do it correctly?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int a = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int a = 1;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = (A)b;
    B b = (B)a; // error
}
```

Comment: Every `B` object is also an `A` object, but not every `A` object is also a `B` object.

Comment: `(A)b` cast [loses information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) (observe that `sizeof(a) < sizeof(b)` ). There is no way to magically recover this lost data.

Comment: Please demonstrate what you want to achieve by what you are trying to do. I ask because in my experience trying to do this kind of conversion indicates a mistake in your class design, especially when it comes to using instances of your classes. So please describe your goal for using this kind of conversion. For what ultimate purpose do you want to use the tool of being able to do this kind of conversion. ( compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the correct approach to handle class inheritance in c++.
Doing this can be dangerous and result in [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) when you copy your subclass object to superclass object.

Maybe what you are trying to achieve can be done through pointers:

```
B b;
A* aa = &b;
B* bb = static_cast<B*>(aa);
```